# Python: How can I create multiple plots for the same function but with different variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, plot

I want to plot the "Growth Factor" for different world models on the same figure but I am struggling to find a way to do it without defining different functions for each variation.

Here is the code I have at the moment, which does produce the plot I want, but it is a very long winded way of doing it.

Note: I have prefixed the variables I want to use (Om and Ov) with a M or V for the matter and Lambda dominated versions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#redshift 
z = np.linspace(0,20,1001)

#Cosmo Density Parameters
#Matter Dominated Universe
MOm = 0.9995
MOv = 0.0005

def MDfunc(z,MOm,MOv):
    A = 5/2
    B = MOm/(1+z)
    C = MOm**(4/7) - MOv
    D = (1-MOm/2)*(1+MOv/70)
    E = A * ( B / ( C+D ) )
    return E

MD = MDfunc(z,MOm,MOv)


#Current Epoch
Om = 0.3
Ov = 0.7

def Dfunc(z,Om,Ov):
    A = 5/2
    B = Om/(1+z)
    C = Om**(4/7) - Ov
    D = (1-Om/2)*(1+Ov/70)
    E = A * ( B / ( C+D ) )
    return E

D = Dfunc(z,Om,Ov)


#Lambda Dominated
VOm = 0.0005
VOv = 0.9995

def VDfunc(z,VOm,VOv):
    A = 5/2
    B = VOm/(1+z)
    C = VOm**(4/7) - VOv
    D = (1-VOm/2)*(1+VOv/70)
    E = A * ( B / ( C+D ) )
    return E

VD = VDfunc(z,VOm,VOv)


#Growth Factor - D+
plt.figure(num=1)
plt.plot(z,D,'r',lw=2,label='Current Epoch')
plt.plot(z,MD,'g',lw=2,label='Matter Dominated')
plt.plot(z,VD,'b',lw=2,label='Lambda Dominated')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

Ideally I wanted to be able to have the different cosmological parameters as an array or tuple but I was met with errors. Something like this would be ideal:

```
Om = (1.0, 0.3, 0.0)
Ov = (0.0, 0.7, 1.0)
```

but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you starting in python?

As I understand you want to do something like this:

```
Om = (1.0, 0.3, 0.0)
Ov = (0.0, 0.7, 1.0)

def Dfunc(z,Om,Ov):
    A = 5/2
    B = Om/(1+z)
    C = Om**(4/7) - Ov
    D = (1-Om/2)*(1+Ov/70)
    E = A * ( B / ( C+D ) )
    return E

d = []
z = 12  # use magic value here
for om, ov in zip(Om, Ov):
    result = Dfunc(z, om, ov)
    print("Calculating Dfunc for: z={}, om={}, oz={}; output is: {}".format(
        z, om, ov, result
    ))
    d.append(result)

print(d)
```

this will output:

```
Calculating Dfunc for: z=12, om=1.0, oz=0.0; output is: 0.102564102564
Calculating Dfunc for: z=12, om=0.3, oz=0.7; output is: 0.0398393147638
Calculating Dfunc for: z=12, om=0.0, oz=1.0; output is: 0.0
[0.10256410256410257, 0.039839314763786056, 0.0]
```

Am I right?

Comment: This is along the right lines for what I wanted to achieve, instead I wanted to plot how the growth factor changes with redshift - 'z'.

I used the for loop you made but I'm not sure how I would label each line on the plot.

    for om, ov, in zip(Om, Ov):
        result = Dfunc(z, om, ov)
        plt.plot(z,result,lw=2)